# React Navigation check when this.props.navigation.state.params change

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a problem with `this.props.navigation.state.params`.

I have a Drawer Navigator that have some menus, and some menus have submenus, when I tap a submenu the app loads a "Category", for example. All submenus from "Category" menu will be redirected to the same screen, but everyone has its own id and title.

The redirect is made with this line:
`this.props.navigation.navigate(menu.route, { submenu });`

The problem is, when I navigate to this screen for the first time, I get the id from `this.props.navigation.state.params.submenu.id` and I send a request to load the contents of this particular id. But, when I open the drawer and tap on another submenu of the same "Category" menu, the id and title in the `this.props.navigation.state.params.submenu` object changes, but I can't dispatch a new request to fetch data with the new id. I'using componentDidMount() to fetch the data the first time (and I know componentDidMount() only fire once), but I can't find what other lifecycle method I can use to dispatch this new request.

I will paste the portions of my code below:

SideMenu.js (the custom Drawer menu component):

```
onHandleSubMenuPress = (menu, submenu) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(menu.route, { submenu });
}
```

Categories.js (the screen that receives the props and loads data):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadMorePosts();
}

loadMorePosts = () => {
    const { id } = this.props.navigation.state.params.submenu;

    if (this.props.nextPage <= this.props.totalPages) {
        this.props.loadCategoryPosts(id, this.props.nextPage);
    }
}
```

I have some control for pages, that I'm using for a infinite scroll on a flatlist, but I'm almost sure it will not be a problem, since I will need to reset those two props to the default state when the navigation params change.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: have you try componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but the props at `this.props.navigation.state.params.submenu` don't change in this method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help but give it a try:

```
   resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: menu.route, params:{item:submenu} }),

    ],
  });
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

resetting the navigation you can use componentDidMount every time